# ASP Net core razor pages building/publishing from VSTS

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, msbuild

I have an ASP .NET core razor pages project, and I'm trying to publish it to Azure using VSTS, actually everything works fine when I publish from VS, I hit right click in the project, select Publish, use my Publish profile from my azure service app, and the project gets publish and the site works perfect, I can see that the .dlls and PrecompiledViews.dlls files are there, along with the wwwroot folder files/directories, etc.

But when I create a build in VSTS, and choose the ASP .NET core template, the project gets published without compiling, any advice on how to get the project published from VSTS will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, I believe when you mean VSTO, you are meaning Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS).

In VSTS, the ASP.NET Core build template is only for publishing and it does not release into an App Service (If you are using Azure). For that, ideally, you need to create a separate release definition. Of course, you can add a step to your build definition to do the release as well.

> But when I create a build in VSTO, and choose the ASP .NET core template, the project gets published without compiling

Make sure you have a build step in your build definition and if you have used the default ASP.NET Core template, it's already included.